# Unable to access JIRA and BitBucket from NetGear Wifi Router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, firewall, jira

I installed and configured JIRA and BitBucket on one of my desktop PCs. I want my developers to be able to access JIRA and BitBucket (hosted using tomcat server) from their laptops. The problem is that when I connect their laptops and my desktop PC (which has Windows 10 and Avast Internet Security) with my mobile's hotspot, they are able to access JIRA and BitBucket. But when I connect them with NetGear WiFi Router WNR612v3, they are unable to access these two. I changed the JIRA port and restarted it. I also restarted the router several times. I added the ports to both Windows Defender Firewall and Avast's Firewall. But nothing seems to work. Please help.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by @ionescu77 I tried to setup port forwarding on my router admin portal.

I am using port 8100 and I don't know how to correctly setup port forwarding. 
Please check the image below:
[image]
10.0.0.2 is the IP of the computer hosting JIRA.

Are these settings correct?

Comment: Are all devices connected to the internal side of the router? Or are the users accessing from outside?

Comment: Are all devices on WiFi? If so, do you have a "_client isolation_" type feature enabled?

Comment: @Attie yes all devices are on the WiFi. And I don't know about  "client isolation" although there is a feature on my wifi router called "Wireless Isolation" and it's disabled. Should I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure port forwarding in the router settings (for example [article from Netgear website](https://kb.netgear.com/1166/Port-numbers-for-port-forwarding))?

From the [Bitbucket Install Document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/install-bitbucket-server-on-windows-867338403.html):

> Bitbucket uses ports 7990, 7992, and 7993 by default, are they available?

I am not using netgear but from your screenshot I guess the router will indeed forward the ports range you specified (I have also checked online for some [port-forwarding instructions for netgear](https://portforward.com/netgear/wnr612/)).

Good luck

Comment: Agree, I do not have enough reputation on superuser to comment :-/

Comment: @ionescu77 check my updated question.

Comment: @ionescu77 yes I can access both BitBucket and JIRA from my desktop computer and same ports works when I open BitBucket or JIRA from laptops using 3G mobile hotspot. But they are not working when connected to NetGear Router.

Comment: I did check, the forward settings seem okay. Did you save them and restarted the router (some routers need restart which will occur after changing settings).

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva so Jira is on desktop computer. Do you have wifi card for this desktop machine? Or is it connected via cable to the router?

Comment: Yeah I restarted it but it's not working.

Comment: @ionescu77 It has a USB wifi card and I am connecting it to the router using WiFi

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva if you run ipconfig on your windows dekstop are you able to see IPv4 address as 10.0.0.2 (your dekstop) and default gateway 10.0.0.1 (presumably your netgear router)? And also from the desktop itself can you try from the browser to access your bitbucket server interface?

Comment: @ionescu77 yes I am able to access it from the FireFox and Chrome browsers on my desktop. And ipconfig is showing this 
   IPv4 Address: 10.0.0.2,
   Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0,
   Default Gateway : 10.0.0.1